# Merging arrays recursively PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, merge

I am using this function two merge recursively arrays:

```
function array_merge_recursive_distinct(array &$array1, array &$array2) {

  $merged = $array1;

  foreach($array2 as $key => &$value) {

      if(is_array($value) && isset($merged[$key]) && is_array($merged[$key])) {

          $merged[$key] = array_merge_recursive_distinct($merged[$key], $value);

      } else {

          $merged[$key] = $value;
      }
  }

  return $merged;
}
```

For using this function I am doing the following steps:

- Declare an empty array $outArray = array();
- Doing a while loop where I collect the information I need

  - During the while loop I call the array_merge_recursive_distinct function                to fill the empty array recursively

However the final array contains only the last information it was gathered during the last while loop. I have tried to find a solution but I haven't succeed until now. What Am I doing wrong? 
The recursive function takes all the info during the while loops (I have printed the input arrays in the recursive function) but it seems like it overwrites the merged array over and over again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`CakePHP` have a nice class called `Hash`, it implements a method called `merge()` who does exactly what you need

```
/**
 * This function can be thought of as a hybrid between PHP's `array_merge` and `array_merge_recursive`.
 *
 * The difference between this method and the built-in ones, is that if an array key contains another array, then
 * Hash::merge() will behave in a recursive fashion (unlike `array_merge`). But it will not act recursively for
 * keys that contain scalar values (unlike `array_merge_recursive`).
 *
 * Note: This function will work with an unlimited amount of arguments and typecasts non-array parameters into arrays.
 *
 * @param array $data Array to be merged
 * @param mixed $merge Array to merge with. The argument and all trailing arguments will be array cast when merged
 * @return array Merged array
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::merge
 */
function merge_arrays_recursivelly(array $data, $merge) { // I changed the function name from merge to  merge_arrays_recursivelly
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
    $return = $data;

    foreach ($args as &$curArg) {
        $stack[] = array((array) $curArg, &$return);
    }
    unset($curArg);

    while (!empty($stack)) {
        foreach ($stack as $curKey => &$curMerge) {
            foreach ($curMerge[0] as $key => &$val) {
                if (!empty($curMerge[1][$key]) && (array) $curMerge[1][$key] === $curMerge[1][$key] && (array) $val === $val) {
                    $stack[] = array(&$val, &$curMerge[1][$key]);
                } elseif ((int) $key === $key && isset($curMerge[1][$key])) {
                    $curMerge[1][] = $val;
                } else {
                    $curMerge[1][$key] = $val;
                }
            }
            unset($stack[$curKey]);
        }
        unset($curMerge);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

---

**https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::merge**

**[Hash::merge source code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.9.5/lib/Cake/Utility/Hash.php#L685)**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this might be handy.

```
function array_merge_recursive_distinct(array &$array1, array &$array2) {
    $merged = array_merge($array1,$array2);
    asort($merged);
    $merged = array_values(array_unique($merged));
    return $merged;
}
$array1 = [];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
print_r(array_merge_recursive_distinct($array1,$array2));
$array1 = [1,2,3,6,12,19];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
print_r(array_merge_recursive_distinct($array1,$array2));
// output
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 12
    [7] => 19
)
```

Test it on [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15e0cda7bf99193385c1a448e917c281aaea558f)