# Merge an associative array onto itself

Tags: php

I have an array to build an org chart.

```
 Array
(
[23669852747] => Array
    (
        [500] => Array
            (
                [2491972948] => Array
                    (
                        [1231166368] => TH
                        [9490413968] => JDA
                        [12870445747] => MA
                        [12977638248] => VA3
                        [17780619828] => TW
                    )

                [14878692388] => Array
                    (
                        [5013958588] => GR
                        [5565058248] => RW
                        [9490304728] => KT
                        [14878677648] => DB
                        [17700259647] => KM
                    )

            )

    )

[1113153218] => Array
    (
        [23669852747] => Array
            (
                [500] => Array
                    (
                        [1271769097] => KVG
                        [4077135657] => JS
                        [4084656658] => TB
                        [6222434168] => MS
                        [7791194248] => JH
                        [14776063607] => Jh
                        [14776070467] => Kh
                        [14878692388] => Rn
                    )

                [23761746408] => Array
                    (
                        [2510729147] => DD
                        [5007359557] => HF
                        [9490374108] => JJ
                        [12870445287] => KT
                        [12977588048] => EJ
                    )

            )

        [1310250127] => Array
            (
                [2510739127] => Array
                    (
                        [2510754677] => JC
                        [5013973888] => Jl
                        [6191488947] => Gl
                    )

                [2510806547] => Array
                    (
                        [4077190247] => TSA
                        [4084643158] => KS
                        [5562275597] => JE
                        [5562365547] => BBH
                        [12870264027] => AM
                    )

                [2510774837] => Array
                    (
                        [4077214557] => CS
                        [5013992688] => SW
                        [5562213897] => JC
                        [5565089238] => DH
                    )

                [55] => Array
                    (
                        [5007299037] => IF
                        [6191533887] => JB
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Both 23669852747 and 1310250127 report to 1113153218
I used this code to identify this person

```
if(sizeof($team_array) > 1)
{
    $array_keys = array_keys($team_array);
    foreach($team_array as $dir_id=>$dir_group)
    {
        for($a=0;$a<sizeof($array_keys); $a++)
        {
            $temp_dir = $array_keys[$a];
            if(isset($team_array[$dir_id][$temp_dir])) $sr_dir = $dir_id;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to roll everyone up to 1113153218

```
[1113153218] => Array
    (
        [23669852747] => Array
            (
                [500] => Array
                    (
                        [1271769097] => KVG
                        [4077135657] => JS
                        [4084656658] => TB
                        [6222434168] => MS
                        [7791194248] => JH
                        [14776063607] => Jh
                        [14776070467] => Kh
                        [14878692388] => Array
                           (
                              [5013958588] => GR
                              [5565058248] => RW
                              [9490304728] => KT
                              [14878677648] => DB
                              [17700259647] => KM
                                )
                        [2491972948] => Array
                              (
                               [1231166368] => TH
                               [9490413968] => JDA
                               [12870445747] => MA
                               [12977638248] => VA3
                               [17780619828] => TW
                          )
                    )

                [23761746408] => Array
                    (
                        [2510729147] => DD
                        [5007359557] => HF
                        [9490374108] => JJ
                        [12870445287] => KT
                        [12977588048] => EJ
                    )
                [14878692388] => Array
                    (
                        [5013958588] => GR
                        [5565058248] => RW
                        [9490304728] => KT
                        [14878677648] => DB
                        [17700259647] => KM
                    )                        

            )

        [1310250127] => Array
            (
                [2510739127] => Array
                    (
                        [2510754677] => JC
                        [5013973888] => Jl
                        [6191488947] => Gl
                    )

                [2510806547] => Array
                    (
                        [4077190247] => TSA
                        [4084643158] => KS
                        [5562275597] => JE
                        [5562365547] => BBH
                        [12870264027] => AM
                    )

                [2510774837] => Array
                    (
                        [4077214557] => CS
                        [5013992688] => SW
                        [5562213897] => JC
                        [5565089238] => DH
                    )

                [55] => Array
                    (
                        [5007299037] => IF
                        [6191533887] => JB
                    )

            )

    )
```

Using this code:

```
$new_team_array[$sr_dir]=$team_array[$sr_dir];
foreach($team_array as $dir_id=>$dir_group)
{
    if($dir_id != $sr_dir) {
        foreach($dir_group as $mgr_id=>$mgr_group)
        {
            $new_team_array[$sr_dir][$dir_id][$mgr_id] = $mgr_group;
        }

    }
}
```

When I merge them, I lose some associations, for example 23761746408 in the original has has 5 direct reports, plus another pair of 100 people (omitted) after the merge the 5 direct reports get lost and are when the  two 100 people array are added.

I'm thinking of cycling through all the child arrays to add them individually, but was hoping for a easier way, as I would have to check for the array depth.

I tried using array_merge but lost the key association

Comment: Is it really so hard to post properly indented code? I sometimes think I spend more time fixing indentation here than actually answering questions.

Comment: You need to use a recursive procedure that merges at each level of the hierarchy below a person.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504593/merging-arrays-recursively-php

Comment: Please add more information about how you want to merge these arrays together, we have no idea what the numeric keys mean, or how you are trying to combine them ;)  I suspect you will need recursion to do this properly.